# View keeps returning null to my controller in mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data to the Controller from the View. I have a fairly complex object, which contains one array and one object with values. Whatever I try, it's null in my controller. I have inspected the data with IE9s <kbd>F12</kbd>, and the data is there. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Code in view:

```
    var deletedIds = [];

    $("#spara").click(function () {
        var changedInsertedData = $("#dagbok_grid").getChangedCells('all');
        var theData = { changedInserted: changedInsertedData, deleted: deletedIds };
        $.post('@Url.Action("SaveGridData")', JSON.stringify({ data: theData }), null, 'json');
    })
```

the Controller:

```
    public void SaveGridData(DagbokGridDTO data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.ToString());
    }
```

The Model/DTOs

```
public class DagbokGridRadDTO
{
    public string Kronika { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}

public class DagbokGridDTO
{
    public DagbokGridRadDTO[] changedInserted;
    public string[] deleted;
}
```

The data from IE9 <kbd>F12</kbd> mode:

```
{"data":{"changedInserted":[{"Kronika":"No","Region":"4","id":"2"}],"deleted":["5"]}}
```

I thought that it is supposed to work this way, but in the controller, data.changedInserted and data.deleted is null. I've tried several different ways, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SaveGridData")', JSON.stringify({ data: theData }), null, 'json');
```

use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveGridData")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: theData }),
    success: function(result) {

    }   
});
```

Notice how the `$.ajax` method allows you to set the request Content-Type header to `application/json` which is what you are sending. The `$.post` method doesn't allow you to set this header and the model binder is unable to understand your request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to receive FormCollectiion in the controller and check. Read the data as `form["changedInserted"]` in the controller.

```
public void SaveGridData(FormCollection form)
```